# How do I pass ruby variables to javascript in rails without inline scripts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-security-policy

My rails app's Content Security Policy disallows inline Javascript. This makes it difficult to pass content to the rails app with inline javascript rendered in the views.

Is there a way to pass rails variables to javascript without inline Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using [HTML5 Data Attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)

I added a `div` with `data-*` attributes like so:

```
<%= tag("div", class: 'hidden-user-information', data: {
  intercom_app_id: ENV['INTERCOM_APP_ID'],
  user_id: current_user.id,
  user_name: current_user.profile.name,
  user_email: current_user.email,
  user_created_at: current_user.created_at.to_i
  })  %>
```

And using jQuery, I accessed these in my javascript using:
`$('div.hidden-user-information').data('intercom-app-id');`

Answer (score 3):

- Keep your javascript files in the app/assets/javascripts folder
- In your view files, use hidden fields for the data you want to pass to javascript
- In your javascript files, find that data by using
  `$("#name_of_hidden_field")`

Comment: Hidden fields from forms? I don't want to embed forms in my app :/

Comment: Why not?  It's not doing anything but sitting there.  @amingilani offers about the same solution, except with `data` attributes.

Comment: @AlexanderLozada Forms imply input. IMHO a data attribute was a much more elegant way to handle it. Although, the canonical way would be to put the data in the body tag, it's much more readable to use the `tag_helper`.